# I cannot load 'Excel file' by doing pandas import

Tags: pandas, excel, xlsx

[i am trying to run excel by using "df_xlsx = pd.read_excel('pokemon_data.xlsx')" code but it showing me this error. what is the problem?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4GV3.png)

I am trying to load excel_file  by using the code `df_xlsx = pd.read_excel('X_data.xlsx')`

Comment: Please provide your code and the full stack trace as text,  not a screenshot.

Comment: Pandas stopped supporting xlsx. In order to use read_excel you need to install xlrd. Or you could just import xls files which are still supported.

Comment: If you install the [`openpyxl` library](https://pypi.org/project/openpyxl/), does it work then?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.